# How to add this HTML PHP code in return function?

Tags: php, function

I want to show following HTML code in the place of excerpt in WordPress. In original code WordPress use

```
return '...';
```

I want to add following PHP and HTML code on return:

```
 <div class="share-icons-r">
     <div class="share-r">
      <h3>Share</h3>
     </div>

     <div class="icons-r">
      <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php echo get_permalink();?>&title=<?php the_title(); ?>">
      <img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/fb.png" />
      </a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Maybe following is the complete code of that function

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'x_excerpt_string' ) ) :
function x_excerpt_string( $more ) 
{ 
$stack = x_get_stack();
   if ( $stack == 'integrity' ) 
      {
   return ' ... <div><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="more-link">' . __( 'Read More', '__x__' ) . '</a>

</div>';} 


else if ( $stack == 'renew' )
  {
  return ' ... <a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="more-link">' . __( 'Read More', '__x__' ) . '</a>';} 

else if ( $stack == 'icon' ) 
  {
  return ' ...';
  } 

  else if ( $stack == 'ethos' ) 
  {
  return '...';
  }
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'x_excerpt_string' );
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your html in a .php file. Then write this

```
ob_start();
include 'my_htlm.php';
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

And then return $out.
This will include your html inside you $out var, when you return it via ajax or whatever your method is, you just have to inject it in your page.

Comment: else if ( $stack == 'ethos' ) {
ob_start();
include 'shareicr.php';
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
      
    }

Comment: You forgot the return $out;